# Successfully Installed Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM but now it reverted back to 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Note: Im on OSX 10.6.6

I successfully installed 1.9.2 using RVM. After doing so I ran rvm --default use 1.9.2, which also appeared to work fine. Ran Ruby -v command and sure enough 1.9.2 appeared.

Now, I closed my terminal session and opened a new one, ran ruby -v and it reverted back to 1.8.7

I removed rvm, repeated the install and the same thing happens.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You added rvm to your bash_profile or bashrc script as directed right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the following to your ~/.bash_profile file to ensure that RVM is loaded properly in a terminal session:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```